# SLURM skipping some jobs in job array

Tags: bash, slurm

In my bash script which is made to run on SLURM scheduler, I specified that I want jobs `1-900%10` to be run on the cluster, so 10 jobs in parallel will be found at any time.

I understand that based on `1-900%10` the first 10 must be run, then next 10, etc. Unless one of these finish before the other.

However I am finding out that SLURM is missing some jobs. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Notice that jobs `5,6,7,8` are not there. I am not sure what the reason is, also they are never computed later on.

Here is a snippet of my bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH --job-name=fotrcont
#SBATCH --account=anaccount
#SBATCH --partition=normal
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --mem=16000
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=someone@example.com
#SBATCH --array=1-900%10
```

**UPDATE**
Turns out that for some reason the node the jobs are getting allocated to is drained for some reason. I have specified the node using `nodelist` as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH --job-name=fotrcont
#SBATCH --account=anaccount
#SBATCH --partition=normal
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --mem=16000
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=someone@example.com
#SBATCH --nodelist=onode09 #  HERE 
#SBATCH --array=1-900%10
```

However its now running 5 jobs at a time rather than 10, although I have specified `1-900%10`. I have tried adding more nodes in `--nodelist`and increasing `--node` to 2 or 3 but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hey I'm facing the same issue. How to did you find out the jobs are allocated to drained nodes? Can we see that from user side?

Comment: Hi @Praveen, in my case there was a command like ``sinfo_all`` which shows the status of each node in the HPC cluster. This depends on your HPC cluster's documentation but there must be something of that sort.